# Representable functions on System T

Tags: lo.logic, type-theory, formal-systems

In Proof and Types by Girard et alii. Section 7.4.2, I think that the authors want to show that:

(1) *The set of functions definable in System T coincides with the set of
recursive functions whose termination is provable in Peano arithmetic*

I don't understand the arguments given to support this thesis.

> In particular, if t is a closed term of type $Int \to Int$ of **T**, it
>   induces a function $|t|:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ defined by:
>
> $|t|(n) = m$ iff $t \overline{n} \leadsto \overline{m}$ $[\ldots]$
>
> The functions $|t|$ are clearly calculable: the
>   normalization algorithm gives $|t|(n)$ as a function of $n$. So those
>   functions representable in **T** are recursive. Can we characterize the
>   class of such functions?

This is how I read this parragraph:

1. Regarding calculability of $|t|$: using the iff one computes $|t|(n)$ by computing $t \overline{n} \leadsto \overline{m}$. Then $\overline{m}$ syntax can be more complex that an integer  and in order to obtain $m$ one has to rewrite it into a normal form (which should be an integer by the term's type).
2. Regarding recursivity: I believe that they stress that the normalization begins with term $t \overline{n}$ and thus $|t|$ is indirectly "recursive" in its argument.

The next parragraph seems to confirm this view:

> $[\ldots]$ Seen as a partial algorithm, $|t|$ amounts to looking for
>   the normal form, and, in the case where this succeeds, writing it. The
>   normalization theorem is thus a proof of program guaranteeing
>   termination of all algorithms obtained from $T$.

From here I get the idea that every function written in $T$ is terminating. The next parragraph comes as a surprise though:

> Now, what are the mathematical principles necessary to prove the
>   reducibility of a fixed term t?
>
> - to be able to express the reducibility of t and of its subterms: one must be able to write a finite number of reducibilities, which can be
>     done in Peano arithmetic (PA)
> - to be able to reason by mathematical induction on this finite number of reduciblity predicates; that can again be done in PA, modulo some
>     awful coding without significant interest (Godel numbering).
>
> Summing up, the termination is provable in arithmetic: we say that
>   $|t|$ is provably total in PA.

If every function was terminating in System T why would one want to prove in PA specifically?

My question is if you can solve the doubts I presented or if you have your own way of showing statement (1)?

Comment: The syntax of $\overline{m}$ is *not* "more complicated". The notation $\overline{m}$ means "numeral $m$", so the statement is that in fact when we normalize $t \overline{n}$ we get a numeral. And this is not a research-level question, it belongs on cs.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If every term in system T terminates, then $t\overline{n}\leadsto\overline{m}$ for every numeral $n$, and it is easy to show that a normal form $\overline{m}$ in the empty context is a numeral as well (and cannot be more complex!). In addition, it is easy to show, **if the term $t\overline{n}$ is normalizing**, that computing the normal form $\overline{m}$ can be done by a Turing machine, which is to say that the function $|t|$ is [recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9C-recursive_function) (the terminology is slightly confusing here). This is what is meant by the first paragraph you have quoted.

Furthermore, every fact stated above can be easily proven in $\mathrm{PA}$, **except the normalization of an arbitrary term of system T**. They go on to show that each *individual* term $t$ can be shown to be normalizing in $\mathrm{PA}$ wich they suggest implies that every term $t$ defines a function in $\mathrm{PA}$: for every term $t:\mathrm{Int}\rightarrow\mathrm{Int}$, there is a proposition $\phi_t(x,y)$ such that
$$\mathrm{PA}\vdash \forall x\exists! y\phi_t(x,y)$$

and

$$\mathrm{PA}\vdash\phi_t(\overline{n},\overline{m})$$
iff
$$|t|(n)=m$$

As the following pages explain, the other direction is provable as well, that is to every $\phi$ with the first property, there is some term $t$ in system T that corresponds to it.